# LINQ OrderBy string parameter

Tags: linq, sorting, gridview, parameters

I'm sure this isn't the most efficient way, but I have a LINQ statement and want to OrderBy a field based off a switch case (this is in the OnSorting Event of a GridView)

```
switch (e.SortExpression)
{
    case "Date":
    field = "btu.Date";
    break;
}

var ds (from btu in dc.BTUs
        join zone in dc.BTUZones on btu.BTUZoneKey equals zone.BTUZoneKey
        orderby field ascending
        select new { btu.BTUKey, btu.Date, zone.BTUZoneName, btu.BTUValue }).ToList();
gv.DataSource = ds;
gv.DataBind();
```

my guess is I can't place a string literal in the query. Should I change my Sort Expression to match the field I want to OrderBy on or is there a way to place a parameter in the query and it accept it (I can't orderby date I need to orderby btu.Date)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try code:

you have directly could not  used Linq Object in  btu 
So i have alter solution this problem.

```
var ds = (from btu in dc.BTUs
    join zone in dc.BTUZones on btu.BTUZoneKey equals zone.BTUZoneKey
    select new { btu.BTUKey, btu.Date, zone.BTUZoneName, btu.BTUValue }).ToList();


    switch (e.SortExpression)
    {
         case : "Date":
         ds= ds.OrderBy(c=>c.Date).ToList();
         break;
         case : "Name"
         ds= ds.OrderBy(c=>c.BTUZoneName).ToList();
         break;
    }
```

and add Another Solution :

Using Linq System.Linq.Dynamic

Go to Vs studio->Tools->NewGet Package Manager->Package Manager Console

Enter Command

Install Install-Package System.Linq.Dynamic -Version 1.0.7

This Reference Add Your Project

After Using below Code:

```
using System.Linq.Dynamic;


string Field="";
switch (e.SortExpression)
{
     case : "Date":
     Field= "Date";
     break;
     case : "Name"
     Field= "BTUZoneName";
     break;
}

var ds = (from btu in dc.BTUs
    join zone in dc.BTUZones on btu.BTUZoneKey equals zone.BTUZoneKey
    select new { btu.BTUKey, btu.Date, zone.BTUZoneName, btu.BTUValue })
    .OrderBy(Field).ToList();
```

Comment: Worked like a charm! I just had to also have (field + " ascending") and I got exactly what I needed. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps the easiest way to get LINQ to sort on arbitrary runtime data is to install the [System.Linq.Dynamic NuGet package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Linq.Dynamic/).  (Here's a link to documentation about the [library's dynamic operators](https://github.com/kahanu/System.Linq.Dynamic/wiki/Dynamic-Expressions).)

However, you'll have to change your LINQ from query syntax to method syntax:

```
using System.Linq.Dynamic;

...

var ds =
  dc.BTUs
  .Join(dc.BTUZones,
        btu => btu.BTUZoneKey,
        zone => zone.BTUZoneKey,
        (btu, zone) => new { btu.BTUKey, btu.Date, zone.BTUZoneName, btu.BTUValue })
  .OrderBy("BTUZoneName") // Or you can use a string variable
                          // or function call for the parameter.
  .ToList();
```

Another way of building dynamic runtime LINQ queries is to create your own custom expression trees.  (This is how the code in System.Linq.Dynamic is implemented.)  This is a Microsoft [article that explains the basics](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/expression-trees/how-to-use-expression-trees-to-build-dynamic-queries).